# Can you help me find gain of amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, inverting-amplifier

[image]

I need to find the gain of this amplifier, but I am confused what should I do. My attempt says answer is 1.6.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you shows us what have you tried so far? We do not solve homework exercises here. We want to see that you have put effort on solving the problem and where did you stuck on the process. At the end, also make the title of the question more problem-specific.

Comment: What I have done is Vi/R= Vo/ [{(R||R)+R}||R]+R
Therefore Vo/Vi= 1.6

Comment: This not homework this is previous year paper , I don't have the solution

Comment: Edit and add whatever you have tried (The Vi/R... equation) to the question, not here on the comments. Homework/previous paper, whatever it is, we want to see the effort.

Comment: @SamarthSharma You are calculating it with resistances in parallel, where do you see any resistors in parallel?
Start at  the output and follow the feedback circuit back to the input, what kind of circuits do the resistors look like? What happens to the output voltage as it goes through those circuits?

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating this methodically, starting with voltages marked in red and currents (green arrows). Pay attention to the signs.

[image]

Comment: Did you get -1.6 when you worked through my suggested exercise?

Comment: So i have apply voltage divider rule at A B

Comment: Ohm's law is enough.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll do so

Answer (score 0):

[image: paper reply]

I tried it by voltage divider rule. Please check .

Comment: I didn't check your algebra, but the answer is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance